# Criar um botão em um ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Eu estou fazendo um aplicativo e ao final da inserções de dados o usuário vai visualizar um resumo com uma `listView`. Até ai tudo bem, mas quero criar, logo em baixo depois da `listview`, um botão de concluir, mas eu não consigo colocar, se eu colocar dentro do XML, ele insere o botão dentro de todos os itens. Como faço isso?

Meu XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/tema"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       />
    <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/palavras"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Meu código:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        String [] tema = new String[] {"Tema1", "Tema2", "Tema3"};
        String [] tempo = new String[] {"1:20", "2:32", "1:10"};
        String [] palavras = new String[] {"Palavras, curió, celular, computador","Camisa, mochila, Sara, SBC","Tunts, Tunts, Quero, ver"};

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
            HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
            item.put("tema", tema[i]+": "+tempo[i]);
            item.put("palavras", palavras[i]);
            list.add(item);
        }

        // Simpler Adapter

        String[] from = new String[] {"tema","palavras"};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tema, R.id.palavras};
        setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this,list,R.layout.activity_main,from,to));

    }
```

Comment: Teria como mostrar o seu XML?

Comment: O seu problema é com seu `LinearLayout` ou `RelativeLayout` que estás utilizando para manter o `ListView`, provavelmente a propriedade `Orientation` do seu layout está incorreta...

Comment: Adicionei o código. Como consigo colocar o botão ai, porque se eu adiciono no xml, ele cria um botão para cada par de itens.

Comment: Esse `XML` que você passou é o da `ListView`, basta fazer o que propõe a resposta e inserir o botão no final do `XML` que está a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe mais de uma forma de resolver esse problema, inclusive por meio de fragmentos.

Essa forma abaixo é uma das mais simples e creio que vá te atender.

Através do atributo

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

o layout permanecerá fixo no rodapé da tela. A lista por sua vez "passará" por baixo do baixo do layout o que poderá esconder parcial ou integralmente algum item. Para evitar isso inclua

```
android:paddingBottom="48dp"
```

na sua lista (Ajuste os valores de acordo com sua necessidade). Dessa forma o final do scroll da lista coincidirá com o início do layout em que está inserido o botão.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adicionar"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@null" 
        android:paddingBottom="48dp"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Necessicita criar um `View` que contém a ListView e o Botão. Algo assim deve funcionar.

```xml
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="7dp" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adicionar"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:listSelector="@null" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/adicionar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/adicionar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Seria bom um `android:layout_below="@id/lista"` no `Button` para que um não sobreponha o outro caso a lista fique muito grande.

Comment: João, o código que te passei é para o XML da lista, você usou o código no XML do adapter da lista ("linha/item da lista").